# append results of sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two sql queries.

```
select EmployeeID,FName from [Mydatabase].[dbo].EMPLOYEE_TABLE where EmployeeID not in
(select ManagerID from [Mydatabase].[dbo].ORG_UNIT where OrgUnitID = '5')and OrgUnitID = '5'
```

this returns two rows.
and there is another query..

```
(select EmployeeID,FName from [Mydatabase].[dbo].EMPLOYEE_TABLE where EmployeeID in
(select ManagerID from [Mydatabase].[dbo].ORG_UNIT where ParentTeamID = '5'))
```

this returns one row.

i want to combine the results so as to get ultimately three rows.. is there a way to do that???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  EmployeeID, FName
FROM    EMPLOYEE_TABLE
WHERE   EmployeeID NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  ManagerID
        FROM    ORG_UNIT
        WHERE   OrgUnitID = '5'
        )
        AND OrgUnitID = '5'
UNION ALL
SELECT  EmployeeID, FName
FROM    EMPLOYEE_TABLE
WHERE   EmployeeID IN
        (
        SELECT  ManagerID
        FROM    ORG_UNIT
        WHERE   ParentTeamId = '5'
        )
```

If an employee can match both criteria, replace `UNION ALL` with `UNION` so that one `id` will not be returned twice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you execute them at the same time? You can combine queries (with matching columns) with the "[UNION ALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)" clause.